# iOS : Open PDF in View and Draw on it and Save

Tags: ios, objective-c, pdf, uiwebview

I am able to open a PDF using `UIWebView`( code below ). What i am trying to do is

1) To open a PDF in background of View controller
2) Make some comments on PDF, draw on it 
3) Should be able to take snapshot of view controller

Out of 3 steps above Step 1, 3 I did, I am stuck with doing number 2, how to draw on `UIWebView`

[image]

**Code for Opening a PDF**

```
UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 200, 200)];

NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.iscp.ie/sites/default/files/pdf-sample.pdf"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:targetURL];
[webView loadRequest:request];

[self.view addSubview:webView];
```

**Code for taking snapshot of WebView**

```
-(UIImage*)captureScreen:(UIView*) viewToCapture
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(viewToCapture.bounds.size);
    [viewToCapture.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return viewImage;
}
```